# Add a var from HTML to PHP for FPDF use

Tags: php, html, variables, fpdf, var

As mentioned in the title, I would like to get a variable back from an "input" in my separate HTML file.

```
<input type="text" id="client" name="clientTest" required minlength="1" maxlength="30" size="30">
```

To put it in my PHP file for FPDF.

I suppose that I have to use the "name" attribute of the input with a function linked in the PHP in this zone :

```
class myPDF extends FPDF{
//code...
},
```

Answer (score 0):

`$_GET['clientTest']` (or `$_POST['clientTest']`) contains the value of `clientTest` input field e.g. `echo $_GET['clientTest'];` would show the fields input